# The "calculus" of sums, i.e. $\sum_{j=0}^{2k}-\sum_{j=0}^k$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

I have a question regarding the "calculus" of sums. Namely, if

$$x:=\sum_{j=0}^{2k}\alpha_j\qquad\text{and}\qquad y=\sum_{j=0}^k\alpha_j,$$
is it generally correct that
$$x-y=\left(\sum_{j=0}^{2k}-\sum_{j=0}^k \right)\alpha_j=\sum_{j=0}^{2k-k}\alpha_j=\sum_{j=0}^k\alpha_j?$$

Comment: No, not correct.

Comment: What's generally correct is $$x-y=\sum\limits_{j=k+1}^{2k}\alpha_j$$

Comment: $(a_0 + a_1 + a_2) - (a_0+a_1) = a_2$, not $a_0+a_1$